# How to connect two machines via wifi and no other hardware?

Tags: wifi

Without using any other hardware, I want to connect two machines that have wifi, so that I can transfer files between them, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at setting up an [Ad-hoc](http://compnetworking.about.com/od/wireless/ht/setupadhocwifi.htm) connect

Comment: I'd like to add that the Ad-hoc mode seems to have bugs on any system I tried (Ubuntu, Gentoo, Windows XP, Windows Vista, Windows 7) and it takes 15 minutes if I'm lucky to set it up each time (multiply networks with different securities etc.). Current kernels seems to have problem with setting WPA2 WiFi network. Not that there is alternative...

Comment: @Maciej Were you using NetworkManager?

Comment: @Tshepang: On Gentoo & Ubuntu yes. Part of my troubles are described on https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=635189 .

Comment: @Maciej: I've never really had any good experience with ad-hoc mode either, but meh.